# fmt formatNumber type="currency" shows "¤" instead of actual currency symbol

Tags: spring, jstl, currency-formatting

I have the following code to show an amount as currency:

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="currency" value="${camp.montoTotal}"/>
```

When I run the application in Eclipse (actually I am using STS), it looks good: "$500".
But when I deploy the WAR file to the server (using Tomcat8 on Ubuntu LTS 14.04), it shows "¤500", i.e., shows the generic currency marker instead of the actual sign. I tried to force the locale with:

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Language" content="es-AR">
<fmt:setLocale value="es-AR"/>
```

but with the same result. Why can it be?

Comment: I found something strange: this problem happens only with Chrome! If I use IE or Edge, it shows the $ sign correctly. Also, if I browse the site from Chrome, IE or Edge served from the Eclipse server in localhost, it works fine. The combination that fails is Tomcat remote server + Chrome. Tried Chrome on smartphone and also fails.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer!!

Originally I had the messageSource bean configured in the app-config xml. When I moved it to the applicationContext xml, the problem was solved. I had to do this because I also had problems when trying to access message properties in the controller with getMessage function.

```
  <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
       <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
  </bean>
```

Conclusion: messageSource must be configured in the application context, not in the root configuration xml.

Answer (score 1):

first, you need to import the tag library:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
```

next, set the country with **setLocale**

```
<fmt:setLocale value="es-AR"/>
```

then you can format the number with **formatNumber** tag

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${camp.montoTotal}" type="currency" currencySymbol="$"/>
```

in the attribute you can add the **currencySymbol** that you want to use.

Hope it helps you.
Regards,